# Firebase - only allow login from app using password & email

Tags: ios, firebase

I'm building an iOS app using Firebase for all data storage. The user creates an account and logs in with password and email. For security reasons, I would like to limit the login, or at least the read and write access, to the app only. I don't want it to be possible for "anyone" to create accounts and access data unless they are using the app.

As I understand it, it's possible for anyone to access the data, as long as they're logged in, if they find out the URL to my Firebase database. This seems like a big security risk to me.

I have of course implemented security rules, but logged in users can still read - and write - data to the database at different locations so basically they could connect the my Firebase database using the Javascript API and then read and write? And anyone can create user's as long as they know the URL to my database?

Is there some way to prevent this, such as using a custom token while still logging in with email and password?

Answer (score 0):

To answer some of your questions:

> ...but logged in users can still read - and write - data to the database
>   at different locations so basically they could connect the my Firebase
>   database using the Javascript API and then read and write?

You can use [the `$other` rule](https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/guide/securing-data.html#section-dollar-variables) to ensure no extra keys are written to your Firebase database:

```
"$other": {
  ".validate": "false"
},
```

But you can also use more granular rules to ensure that users only have access to the data they need.

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null", // only authed users can read/write
    ".write": "auth != null",
    "users": {
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "auth.uid == $uid", // users can read/write their own data
        ".write": "auth.uid == $uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

> And anyone can create user's as long as they know the URL to my database?

To create users you'll also need to be on a valid origin, that you specified in the App Dashboard. This means that not just anyone with your URL can start creating users.

[image]

Comment: "To create users you'll also need to be on a valid origin, that you specified in the App Dashboard. This means that not just anyone with your URL can start creating users." But that seems to only apply to third-party authentication? And they could potentially create their own iOS app and hook it up to my Firebase database.

Comment: I have implemented the $other rule, but they can still write to allowed nodes/keys. Although I'm doing basic validation in my rules (such as .isNumber() .isString() etc, most of my data validation is done in the app, which they can circumvent if they don't use the app.

Comment: Origin still works for email and password. Also the validation works even if they don't use the app because the security happens on the server

Comment: I was referring to the validation I have in my app, that's done before data is posted to the Firebase database. How does origin work when using the iOS SDK?